# Javascript/Jquery - Detect keypress except when file select dialog is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a modal box overlay that the user edits some information in.  One of the ways to close this overlay is by simply pressing ESC.  I have no problem with this working.  However, within this modal box is a section for uploading a file.  While the user is selecting a file, if the user presses ESC, it closes the 'select file' dialog box, but then that keypress is also detected by my 'modal box close' script.  I do have a confirmation dialog to ask the user if they're sure they want to close the box, but I still don't want the action triggered if they're only trying to close the 'file select' dialog.

What would be the best approach here?  Is there a way to determine whether the browser's focus is on the 'file select' dialog versus part of the actual page?

**UPDATE:**
The first three answers are basically the same, and the solution was so simple I'm actually embarrassed that I even asked.  Thanks for the help.  Normally I'd accept an answer but since the three are the same I'm not really sure how to choose a favorite. I guess I'll just pick one.  That doesn't make the other two any less acceptable, though.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best approach here? Is there a way to determine
>   whether the browser's focus is on the 'file select' dialog versus part
>   of the actual page?

Why make it that complicated, you have the ability to identify if the user has clicked the 'Select File' button, so you can setup a flag variable and set it to true whenever they click this button.

Then your keydown/keyup event can check the flag and handle the scenario accordingly.

**Edit:**

Example code:

```
var SelectFileCode = {
   IsSelectingFile: false,

   Click: function() {
      this.IsSelectingFile = true;
      //do stuff here to open dialog
   },
   KeyDown: function(event) {
     if (this.IsSelectingFile && event.which == 27) //pressed ESC
        //don't close modal, just close select dialog
   }
};

$(function() {
    $('.selectBtn').click(SelectFileCode.Click);
    $('.modal').keydown(SelectFileCode.KeyDown);
});
```

You'll need to make sure to reset `IsSelectingFile` appropriately but this would be the general approach.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you provided an example.  Even though I didn't need it, perhaps it could help someone else.  I don't know why I even asked this question.  It should have been obvious to me.  I guess I was just so focused on detecting the dialog that I forgot I could detect the user actions up to that point.  Again, thanks.

Comment: @vertigoelectric `...I'm actually embarrassed that I even asked`. No reason to be embarrassed. It is a skill that you have to develop over time to not over-complicate the flow of logic/control of a program. And sometimes, we just brain fart. =P

Answer (score 1):

set a flag variable true when the dialog opens.When dialog close change it to false.Apply keypress logic if it is false.

Comment: I could only accept one answer, so I chose the one giving the most helpful details.  I voted yours up, though.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable(a flag) when the browse for file button is pressed. Later where you close the modal box, simply check the flag and if it is on, don't close the box.